# Как не выделять пробел перед словом?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

[image: Имеется следующая строка и регулярное выражение]

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы не выделялся пробел перед словом "main"?

Comment: Может, `(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+`

Comment: Благодарю, @wiktor-stribiżew

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать

```
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/RkmxPG/1).

Шаблон `(?<!\S)` означает, что сразу перед текущей позицией должен быть пробельный символ или начало строки.

Никогда не используйте `[A-z]`, так как этот символьный класс также находит  `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, `` ` ``:

[image: См. скрин]