# Ошибка с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Вот моя регулярка:

```
(?<Property>[ ]*[A-z|0-9|А-я]+[ ]*):(?<Value>[A-z|0-9|А-я]+);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему такое значение у Value?

Comment: `[A-z]` находит не только буквы (оно находит также ``[``, ``\``, `]`, `^`, `_`, ``"`"``), используйте `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Также см. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1030054/182013).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо